# Can curve25519 keys be used with ed25519 keys?

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys, ed25519

Can curve25519 keys be used with ed25519?

I'd prefer to use ed25519, but there isn't a fast java version.  For my application, I'd like to use curve25519 until I can get a faster ed25519 for java.

At the very least can the curve25519 keys be restricted if some can be converted ed25519?

Comment: The problem is that you don't get the y part of the coordinate when using a montgomery ladder to compute the public key.

Comment: This question appears to be **off-topic** since it turns out it’s more about asking for reference recommendations regarding Java libraries/implementations, instead of [cryptography as defined in the help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The fact that answers point to different libraries underlines this. Note: asking for reference recommendations related to libraries (including crypto-libs) are on-topic at [SoftwareRecommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trevor Perrin [wrote a library](https://github.com/trevp/ref10_extract) doing exactly that. Explanation can be found on in the [curves mailing list archives](https://moderncrypto.org/mail-archive/curves/2014/000205.html).

To convert a Curve25519 public key $x_C$ into an Ed25519 public key $y_E$, with a Ed25519 sign bit of $0$:
$$y_E = \frac{x_C - 1}{x_C + 1} \mod 2^{255}-19$$
The Ed25519 private key may need to be adjusted to match the sign bit of $0$: if
multiplying the Curve25519 private key by the Ed25519 base point
yields a “negative” Ed25519 x-coordinate, then the private key must be negated modulo the order of the base point: $a_E = q - a_C$.

See Trevor Perrin's email and the ensuing thread  for a security analysis.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, no. However, Ed25519 keys can be converted to Curve25519 keys. My [Ed25519 library](https://github.com/nightcracker/ed25519) supports this (or well, it supports DH with Ed25519 keys).

Whether it is secure to use the same key for both signing and Diffie-Hellman, I don't exactly know. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3311/4697) suggests that it is very likely, but it still needs more study.

Comment: Thank you nightcracker!  I think I either have to use Curve25519 at this point or another digital signature algorithm unless if you can help with this.  Thank you so very very much in advance!  http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12949/how-can-k3d3-ed25519-javas-performance-be-improved

Comment: @Gracchus I think you should look into using a C library from Java - there are almost no cryptographers writing libraries in Java.

Comment: Thank you nightcracker!  I've noticed. ;))  I do appreciate your help!

Comment: @nightcracker Come again? Sun JCE, PKCS11 & JSSE + ECC. Then there are Bouncy Castle, IAIK libraries, BSAFE... If you want support for a specific curve, ask on the Bouncy mailing list! Or add it yourself of course!

Comment: @owlstead Sorry, I meant the cryptographers that develop the primitives themselves - they almost never release a Java library. There are a few "cryptography suites" as you've cited, that implement many primitives, but outside of those big suites there isn't much high-quality Java cryptography software available. This means that if you want to use modern cryptography, like Ed/Curve25519, ChaCha, Keccak, BLAKE, Poly1305, that you'll either have to implement it yourself or trust an often badly performing non-scrutinized third-party implementation.

Comment: E.g. I agree that I would have liked it more if those kind of primitives would be made available in Java. Keccak & Skein are inside the Bouncy libs. To be honest, I think Java is only behind C/C++ in this regard, and the default Java SE API contains a pretty good - if somewhat peculiar- interface and a lot of standardized algorithms. Writing in Java is a bit tricky because the signed bytes, immutable BigInteger class and lack of operator overloading makes it tricky to implement cryptographic algorithms compared to C/C++.

Comment: @nightcracker: With "Ed/Curve22519, Chacha, Keccak, Blake, Poly1305" you named examples of cryptographic primitives that actually seem to come with well-optimized implementations in C & ASM. :)

Comment: @sellibitze Eehm maybe you misunderstood me, that was exactly my point.

Comment: @nightcracker: It seems I did. Your last sentence "This means that if you want to use modern cryptography, like Ed/Curve25519, ChaCha, Keccak, BLAKE, Poly1305, that you'll either have to implement it yourself or trust an often badly performing non-scrutinized third-party implementation." sounds to me as if you were saying that there are no well-optimized implementations. But I guess you are talking about Java implementations only.